# Webpack loads in wrong from parent folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to run a watch command on my Webpack in order to compile my code but I always face an issue with my file. Even trying to change the relative paths with some `../` did not work

```
ERROR in code
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../src/code.ts' in '/Users/giardiv/Lines/f-variables'

ERROR in ui
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../src/ui.tsx' in '/Users/giardiv/Lines/f-variables'

ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/giardiv/Lines/src/ui.html' in '  /Users/giardiv/Lines/f-variables':
  Error: Can't resolve '/Users/giardiv/Lines/src/ui.html' in '/Users/giardiv/Lin  es/f-variables'
  ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/giardiv/Li  nes/src/ui.html' in '/Users/giardiv/Lines/f-variables'
```

While my folder tree is quite basic, `f-variables` is the `src` and other files are directly in it

[image]

This is the webpack config

```
const HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin = require('html-webpack-inline-source-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = (env, argv) => ({
  mode: argv.mode === 'production' ? 'production' : 'development',

  // This is necessary because Figma's 'eval' works differently than normal eval
  devtool: argv.mode === 'production' ? false : 'inline-source-map',

  entry: {
    ui: "../src/ui.tsx", // "./src/ui.tsx" calls the same error
    code: "../src/code.ts" // "./src/code.ts" calls the same error
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      // Converts TypeScript code to JavaScript
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, use: 'ts-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },

      // Enables including CSS by doing "import './file.css'" in your TypeScript code
      { test: /\.css$/, use: ['style-loader', { loader: 'css-loader' }] },

      // Allows you to use "<%= require('./file.svg') %>" in your HTML code to get a data URI
      { test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|webp|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader' },
    ],
  },

  // Webpack tries these extensions for you if you omit the extension like "import './file'"
  resolve: { extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.jsx', '.js'] },

  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), // Compile into a folder called "dist"
    publicPath: '/',
  },

  // Tells Webpack to generate "ui.html" and to inline "ui.ts" into it
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: '../src/ui.html',
      filename: 'ui.html',
      inlineSource: '.(js)$',
      chunks: ['ui'],
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin),
  ],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the paths in `entry` are wrong in your `webpack.config.js` file.

It should be set as below since you have `webpack.config.js` besides `src` directory.

```
entry: {
    ui: "./src/ui.tsx",
    code: "./src/code.ts"
},
```

Comment: I forgot to set it back to the initial value, but it does not work with these values either. Still the exact same error.

Just tried the move the config in the src folder but still, I meet an error related to path